# io.debezium.data.VariableScaleDecimal (STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to stream data from Oracle to Postgres with Debezium as source and JdbcSinkConnector by Confluent as sink, and on Sink stage I'm getting this error:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: io.debezium.data.VariableScaleDecimal (STRUCT) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
I'm taking Float value from oracle and, according to documentaion, it sends it to topic like that:
Contains a structure with two fields: scale of type INT32 that contains the scale of the transferred value and value of type BYTES containing the original value in an unscaled form
And in my topic it goes:

```
"payload": {
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "ID": 109,
            "NAME": "spare tire",
            "DESCRIPTION": "24 inch spare tire",
            "WEIGHT": {
                "scale": 1,
                "value": "AN4="
            }
```

How can I transform it in normal Postgres type, like NUMERIC and fix this error?